# XMLHttpRequest: Upload Files and Text with to one url

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, xmlhttprequest, multipartform-data

I need to upload a video file along with some text. So far I can upload the two separately, but now I need to be able to upload both, together. This is my code so far:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', '/upload', true);
var form = new FormData($('.filesForm')[0]);
xhr.send(form);
```

This just uploades the video file. I also have some event listeners for errors and responses but I don't think they matter.

This code is for both the video and the text:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', '/upload', true);

var form = new FormData($('.filesForm')[0]);
var videoName = $('.nameInput').val();

var object = {
  form: form,
  name: videoName
}
xhr.send(object);
```

But neither gets sent. In fact, I could just put both of them in one form, but sadly I can't because they need to be on different parts of the page. Is there some other way to do it? Thank you!

Comment: Can you give us the server side code that handles the upload?

Comment: It's too much code. Forget about it. I'll do the above, is some other way!